# Apex test method error

Tags: testing, salesforce, apex-code

we are having an issue with apex test method. we have an http request in my apex method. i have to creates a test method for this. but we are having an issue

Apex code:

```
public void ReceiveBestAnswer(Id repID){    
        reply = GlobalFunctions.getReplyCreatorDetails(repID);
        System.debug(reply);
        String bestReplyUser = reply.CreatedById;


        profileUser = [select Username,Email from User where Id = :bestReplyUser];
        System.debug('profileUser.Name-->'+profileUser.Username);  
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        req.setEndpoint('http://sandbox.v2.badgeville.com/api/berlin/b95839370dca983955e550296450ec03/activities.json');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setBody('activity[verb]=receive best answer&site=www.grazitti.com&user='+ profileUser.Email );
        try {
            http.send(req);
            System.debug('res-->');
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        } 
}
```

Test method :

```
 public static testMethod void testReceiveBestAnswer() {        
 Reply reply = new Reply();
    String replyId = reply[0].Id;
  //  Id questionID = '906P0000000010KIAQ';
  //  String sql =  'SELECT Id, Title FROM Question';  
 //   Question[] ques = [SELECT Id FROM Question];      
 //   Question quest = ques[0];       
    BadgeVilleWebServiceCallout bv = new BadgeVilleWebServiceCallout();
    bv.badgvilleReceiveBestAnswer(replyId );

}
```

2nd test method:

```
 public static testmethod  void testReceiveBestAnswer1() 
     {

        ID ProfileID = [ Select id from Profile where name = 'Named Marketo Community Portal'].id;
        System.debug('ProfileID --->'+ProfileID );
        Account A1 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        insert A1;        
        List<Contact> ContactList = new List<Contact>();
        Contact C1 = new Contact( AccountID = A1.id, FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'User', 
            email = 'test-user@fakeemail.com' );
        insert C1;


        User u1 = new User( email='test-user@fakeemail.com', contactid = c1.id, profileid = profileid, 
            UserName='test-user@fakeemail.com', alias='tuser1', CommunityNickName='tuser1', TimeZoneSidKey='America/New_York', LocaleSidKey='en_US', EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1',  LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', FirstName = 'Test', LastName = 'User' );
    insert u1;
    System.debug('u1--->'+u1 );




      /* User[] users = [SELECT Id FROM User];
      User u1 = users[0];

      //  Question[] ques = [SELECT Id FROM Question];  
       //System.debug('ques --->'+ques );    
 //   Question quest = ques[0];       
 //   BadgeVilleWebServiceCallout bv = new BadgeVilleWebServiceCallout();
 //   bv.badgvilleReceiveBestAnswer(quest.Id);

 Id questId ;
   Test.startTest();  
   System.RunAs(u1)
        {            
            Question question = new Question();
            question.Title = 'Test';
            question.Body = 'Test';
            question.CommunityId = '09a50000000PNNr';//GlobalFunctions.communityId;
            insert question;  
            System.debug('question-->'+question);              
            questId = question.Id;   
            System.debug('questId --->'+questId );  

            Reply reply1 = new Reply();                
            reply1.Body =  'reply no 1 ques 1';
            reply1.QuestionId = question.Id;                 
            System.debug('reply1--->'+reply1);        
            insert reply1;
        }


      //  BadgeVilleWebServiceCallout bv = new BadgeVilleWebServiceCallout();
     //   bv.badgvilleReceiveBestAnswer(questId);   
        Test.stopTest();    


    }
```

We are trying to implement this with both test methods. but we are unable to  do it. can nay body have any idea how to do this or where i am doing wrong??

Comment: For anyone to be able to help you, you need to explain what error you are getting, on what line. Also, please explain how your test code relates to your production code.

Comment: i would think you would need to give us what the issue is.. Line # and error description could help us give you suggestions.. right now it would be impossible for us give you a solution

Comment: As such we are not getting any error we want to run a test method for our apex method .. we are trying different methods for this but both the methods are not working for us.. so can any bidy suggest hw to createa test method for this..???

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce doesn't allow you to Test external WebServices.

Here, you have an idea of how to [test WebServices](http://sfdc.arrowpointe.com/2009/05/01/testing-http-callouts/).

And here you have a [Salesforce Idea](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrBu).

I hope this help you.